# How come this function returns 0s rather than random numbers

Tags: python

Basically, I'm trying to create a function which goes up and down floors, as it chooses a random number from 1 - 6. However, it returns a bunch of 0s instead of a list of random numbers. This goes on until it reaches the hundredth floor.

I've already tried moving the definition of the 'f' variable to different locations to see if that works and I tried changing the ways it calculates whether to move up or down a floor.

```
def roll():
f=0
arry = []
count = 0
while count is not 100:
    numb = randint(1,6)
    if numb is 1 or 2:
        f-1
    elif numb is 3 or 4 or 5:
        f+1
    else:
        f + randint(1,6)
    count=count+1
    arry.append(f)
return arry
```

The actual results should be a series of random numbers, but I get a bunch of 0s instead.

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to why you get an array of zeros is that each time through the loop, you append the value of `f`, which never changes in the code. It is initialized to 0 early on, but never changed. You will want to write

```
f -= 1
```

and

```
f += 1
```

and

```
f += randint(1,6)
```

However, there are a few more mistakes to correct, which are pretty common for beginners. For example, you wrote:

```
if numb is 1 or 2:
```

which will always be `True` because in Python this is the same as:

```
if (numb is 1) or 2:
```

You should write:

```
if numb == 1 or numb == 2:
```

or even:

```
if numb in (1, 2):
```

Do the same thing for the next condition, for example:

```
if numb in (3, 4, 5):
```

Also, avoid `is not` when dealing with numbers, and use `!=` instead.

This should get you really close to what you are looking for.

Comment: I'd also use `while count < n`. If `while count is not n` loop never breaks if `n > 256`. Why that? Or it's just my machine..

Answer (score 1):

You never modify `f`. Your code has many other issues though.

```py
def roll():
f = 0
arry = []
count = 0
while count is not 100:
    numb = randint(1,6)
    if numb is 1 or 2: # this will always be true
        f -= 1
    elif numb is 3 or 4 or 5:
        f += 1
    else:
        f += randint(1,6)
    count=count+1
    arry.append(f)
return arry
```

```py
def roll():
f = 0
arry = []
count = 0
while count is not 100:
    numb = randint(1,6)
    if numb in (1, 2):
        f -= 1
    elif numb in (3, 4, 5):
        f += 1
    else:
        f += randint(1,6)
    count=count+1
    arry.append(f)
return arry
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are never assigning new values to `f`.
Writing `f+1` or `f-1` doesn't change the value of `f`, but return a new value, which equals to the value of `f` plus or minus 1.
What you should write is:

```py
f = f+1
f = f-1
```

To get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you performed the operations

```
    f-1
    f+1
    f + randint(1,6)
```

instead you should have done

```
   f= f-1
   f= f+1
   f= f + randint(1,6)
```

so function should be

```
def roll():
f=0
arry = []
count = 0
while count is not 100:
    numb = randint(1,6)
    if numb is 1 or 2:
        f=f-1
    elif numb is 3 or 4 or 5:
        f=f+1
    else:
        f=f + randint(1,6)
    count=count+1
    arry.append(f)
return arry
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this...  Problems are already explained.

```
import random

def roll():
    f=0
    arry = []
    count = 0
    while count is not 100:
        numb = random.randint(1,6)
        if numb == 1 or numb == 2:
            f -= 1
        elif numb == 3 or numb == 4 or numb == 5:
            f += 1
        else:
            f = f + random.randint(1,6)
        count += 1
        arry.append(f)
    return arry
roll = roll()
print(roll)
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explaining why it is not working as intended I want to add that using

```
while count is not 100:
```

here is not best idea, technically it works, but `is` is not supposed to be used for integer values comparison, for example:

```
x = 294
print(x is 294)
```

will produce `False`, so for checking if numbers are same you should use `==` operator and checking if are unequal `!=` operator, so in your case `while` should be:

```
while count != 100:
```